# Help with array

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, fatal-error

Hello people a have a problem,

I have a array returned by webservice.

```
Array
(
[GetProductResult] => Array
    (
        [schema] => Array
            (
                [element] => Array
                    (
                        [complexType] => Array
                            (
                                [choice] => Array
                                    (
                                        [element] => Array
                                            (
                                                [complexType] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [sequence] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [element] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [0] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [!name] => codigo
                                                                                [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                            )

                                                                        [1] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [!name] => nome
                                                                                [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                            )

                                                                        [2] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [!name] => imagem
                                                                                [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                            )

                                                                        [3] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [!name] => stock
                                                                                [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [!name] => produto
                                            )

                                        [!minOccurs] => 0
                                        [!maxOccurs] => unbounded
                                    )

                            )

                        [!name] => produtos
                        [!msdata:IsDataSet] => true
                        [!msdata:UseCurrentLocale] => true
                    )

                [!id] => produtos
            )

        [diffgram] => Array
            (
                [produtos] => Array
                    (
                        [produto] => Array
                            (
                                [codigo] => 13251
                                [nome] => Nova Development - Print Explosion Deluxe Mac
                                [imagem] => http://www.novadevelopment.com/images/3DBox_w250_tcm23-129399.jpg
                                [stock] => 0
                                [!diffgr:id] => produto1
                                [!msdata:rowOrder] => 0
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

i request from a webservice using id_produto from my Database but sometimes i got this error:

> Cannot use string offset as an array in php

AND ARRAY RESULT IS:

```
Array
(
[GetProductResult] => Array
    (
        [schema] => Array
            (
                [element] => Array
                    (
                        [complexType] => Array
                            (
                                [choice] => Array
                                    (
                                        [element] => Array
                                            (
                                                [complexType] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [sequence] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [element] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [0] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [!name] => codigo
                                                                                [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                            )

                                                                        [1] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [!name] => nome
                                                                                [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                            )

                                                                        [2] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [!name] => imagem
                                                                                [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                            )

                                                                        [3] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [!name] => stock
                                                                                [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [!name] => produto
                                            )

                                        [!minOccurs] => 0
                                        [!maxOccurs] => unbounded
                                    )

                            )

                        [!name] => produtos
                        [!msdata:IsDataSet] => true
                        [!msdata:UseCurrentLocale] => true
                    )

                [!id] => produtos
            )

        **[diffgram] =>**
    )
```

)

Now how i avoid this error? im trying to access to array with this:

```
$stock = $result['GetProductResult']['diffgram']['produtos']['produto']['stock'];
```

Someone can help with one If to pass the error?

Cumps

Comment: I have no idea how to solve your problem. I just wanted to say - you poor soul.  Arrays like that ought to be banned.  Perhaps we can amend the Geneva Convention to define them as torture?

Comment: Looks like wrong coding on webservice's part to be honest. I cannot imagine an array key "!msdata:IsDataSet"...Looks like a function call.

Comment: Is the second array a var_dump of `$result` when you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means that at item that you are trying to access as an array is actually a string. Make sure that all of the nested elements in your arrays are actually arrays themselves, and not strings.

Comment: how can i know if $result['GetProductResult']['diffgram'] is a array or a string?

Comment: [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/function.is-array.php) seems to do what you need.

Comment: if( is_array($result['GetProductResult']['diffgram']) ) { ... }

Comment: $sub = $result['GetProductResult']['diffgram'];
 if($sub != ""){
  $stock = $result['GetProductResult']['diffgram']['produtos']['produto']['stock'];
  echo "<pre>O produto $id_produto há $stock em stock</pre><br/>";
 }

This resolve my problem thanks :)